# Simplify an XMLObject by keeping only specific elements

Tags: xml

I would like to extract from an XMLObject only the XMLElements with a specific tag.

Inspired from the *Mathematica* help (section transforming XML, introduction, the example with the colours), I have tried this code :

Definition of the XMLObject:

```
XMLtest = 
  XMLObject[
    XMLElement["YO", {}, 
      {XMLElement["YO", {}, 2], 
         XMLElement["BA", {}, 
           {XMLElement["YO", {}, 
             {XMLElement["BA", {}, 2]}], XMLElement["BA", {}, 2]}]}]]
```

[image]

Code so as to suppress all the elements different from "YO" in order to keep only the elements with the tag "YO":

```
XMLtest2 = XMLtest /. XMLElement[Except["YO"], _, _] -> Sequence[]
```

[image]

The above code works well.

Code so as to suppress the XMLElements without the tag "BA":

```
XMLtest2 = XMLtest /. XMLElement[Except"BA", _, _] -> Sequence[]
```

[image]

For this latter code, I have a problem with the answer because I obtain only the XMLObject. However, I would like to obtain a tree of XMLElements under the XMLObject.

Please help me to correct my code in this lastRoutine clean-up case?

Comment: Somehow you ended up with the `\[RightArrow]` character when instead you need either plain text `->` or `\[Rule]`.  Correct this and your replacement will work.  I am closing this question as a "simple syntax error" now.  If you find that I am mistaken or have other problem please comment here, starting your comment with `@Mr.Wizard` so that I will be notified.

Comment: Sometimes I like this way of defining a behavior for an XML element: `xmltest2 = Block[{XMLElement},  XMLElement["BA", __] := Sequence[];  XMLtest]` and `xmltest3 = Block[{XMLElement},  XMLElement[Except["YO"], __] := Sequence[];  XMLtest]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That seems harder than using `DeleteCases`; do you find otherwise?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For any given narrow task, there is probably a simpler solution than the one I proposed.  But when I use XML data, which is not often so take this with a grain of salt, I often want to do several things that are functions of the tag, attributes, and data.  I find it easier to think about such a problem in terms of `XMLElement` as a function.  OTOH, there is a difference I overlooked at first.  The OP's code would do one replacement, mine three, due to `ReplaceAll` vs. evaluation.  So maybe my comment isn't so helpful here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I made some corrections. Thanks a lot for your very constructive help.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for help. If you have news ideas, so as to correct my code (more generalized, cf case that i want to suppress the XMLElements differents from BA, it will be great.

Comment: I try also this code : XMLtest3 = 
 Cases[XMLtest, _XMLElement, Infinity] //. 
  XMLElement[tag : "YO", attributes_, data_] :> 
   XMLElement[tag , attributes, data] but it doesn't work. Thank you for your ideas in order to keep in a XMLObject only the XMLElements with a specific tag and also keep a tree structure in the XMLObject.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure what you want.  I think it is this, but it does not reproduce the tree you have in the question for the `Except["YO"]` case.

```
contractElement[xml_, tagpat_] := Block[{XMLElement},
   XMLElement[tagpat, _, data_] /; FreeQ[data, XMLElement] := Sequence[];
   XMLElement[tagpat, _, data_] := Sequence @@ data;
   xml
   ];

contractElement[XMLtest, Except["YO"]] // TreeForm
contractElement[XMLtest, Except["BA"]] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Side note: I thought the syntax for [`XMLObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLObject.html) is `XMLObject[type][data]`, which does not quite conform with you example.  For instance, this might produce an error, if a root is required:

```
XMLtest2 = 
  XMLObject[
   XMLElement["YO", {},
    {XMLElement["BA", {}, 2], 
     XMLElement["BA", {},
      {XMLElement["YO", {}, 2],
       XMLElement["BA", {}, 2]}]}]];
XMLtest2 // TreeForm
contractElement[XMLtest2, Except["BA"]] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank a lot for your help.
Your code perfectly answers to my need.
However, I would prefer a code with an approach as in this post :
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83622/suppress-attributes-of-all-xmlelements-of-a-xmlobject?noredirect=1#comment226460_83622
That is to say a way which easily permit to add more conditions on the attributes of an XMLElements. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can define `XMLElement[tag_, attr_, data_]  := ...` however you want. Such as `XMLElement[tag_, attr_, data_] := `XMLElement[tag, Join[attr, myattributes], data]`, if you wish to add a list `myattributes` to the list of attribute `attr`.

Comment: @Bendesarts please, take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).